# preg_replace по шаблону

Tags: php

Всем привет. Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Что есть:

```
$url = 'mailto:test@email.com';
$string = 'Нажмите на [[reply_link|эту ссылку]] для ответа.';
```

Нужно из этой строки получить следующую:

```
$string = 'Нажмите на <a href="mailto:test@email.com">эту ссылку</a> для ответа.';
```

`href` должен браться из переменной. Текст ссылки должен замениться из шаблона (после |). Как можно это реализовать? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Текст ссылки должен замениться из шаблона (после |). Как можно это реализовать?*

Нужно построить шаблон, который будет соответствовать всей подстроке `[[reply_link|эту ссылку]]`, а для получения текста после символа **|** использовать подмаску *(сохраняющие скобки)* с последующей подстановкой найденного совпадения в html-тег `<a>$1</a>`:

```
$url = 'mailto:test@email.com';
$str = 'Нажмите на [[reply_link|эту ссылку]] для ответа.';

$patt = '~\[\[[^|]+\|([^]]+)]]~u';
$repl = '<a href="' . $url . '">$1</a>';

echo preg_replace($patt, $repl, $str);
```

Результат:

```
Нажмите на <a href="mailto:test@email.com">эту ссылку</a> для ответа.
```